# Select nth column in database table

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I am talking about SQL Server 2008. I have table with three `nvarchar` columns. I want to select first column at Nth row, second column from Mth row, third column from Kth row where M,N,K are not equal one to another.

How to write such a query? Also is it possible to select random row?

Comment: The `n-th` row - ordered by what?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I mean column at Nth row, I will have my question edited.

Comment: OK - but again: if you want to get the "n-th", "m-th" row - you have to define an **ordering** by some column. Without explicit ordering - there is no "n-th" row....

Comment: Order does not matter for me - order by first column, or date inserted - no difference. So let's say order by insertion date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a CTE with a `ROW_NUMBER()` function to achieve this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT 
      Column1, Column2, Column3,
      (your list of additional columns - if needed),
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY InsertionDate)
)
SELECT 
    FirstValue = (SELECT Column1 FROM CTE WHERE RN = N),
    SecondValue = (SELECT Column2 FROM CTE WHERE RN = M),
    ThirdValue = (SELECT Column3 FROM CTE WHERE RN = K)
```

You need to replace the `N, M, K` with actual integer values in this query - or define SQL variables to hold those three values.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i1 int;
declare @i2 int;
declare @i3 int;
SET @i1=2;
SET @i2=4;
SET @i3=1;

;with t1 as
(
select *,row_number() over(order by (select 0)) as rn  from t
)
 select max(CASE rn WHEN @i1 then N1 else '' end),
        max(CASE rn WHEN @i2 then N2 else '' end),
        max(CASE rn WHEN @i3 then N3 else '' end)
        from t1 where rn in (@i1,@i2,@i3);
```